# How to get popup when my table has data instead blank or None?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a django project. where my requirement is if a table has all the data then on button click i should get a alert that that table has data.
code for the table

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<div class="container" style=" margin-left: 68%;">
<a href="# id="assignbtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Assign Status </a>
       
    </div>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Robot</th>
    <th>Short Desc</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo1</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo2</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo3</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Not-Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo4</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>Running</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

in this table in the column **Status** has value like Available, Not-Available, Running then I need a alert like all the status are assigned on click of **assign status** button. But if in the **status** column there's value like Null, None or black then there no alert needed.
How to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's many ways you can accomplish what you want and the below is just one of them.

I added a class `.status` for each status column to then get every element with that class and check if they match any of the string in array `statusOptions`.

```js
const statusOptions = ["None"];

var btn = document.getElementById("assignbtn");

btn.onclick = function() {
  var fireAlert = true;
  var statuses = document.querySelectorAll(".status");
  statuses.forEach(function(elem) {
    if (!elem.innerText || statusOptions.includes(elem.innerText)) {
      fireAlert = false;
    }
  });
  if (fireAlert) {
    alert(' All the status are assigned');
  }
};
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<div class="container" style=" margin-left: 68%;">
<a href="#" id="assignbtn" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" role="button"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Assign Status </a>
       
    </div>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Robot</th>
    <th>Short Desc</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo1</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td class="status">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo2</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td class="status">Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo3</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td class="status">Not-Available</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Demo4</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td class="status">Running</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Hi @iamdlm, Here i dont know the status values ...those are dynamic and dependent on other tool. so i can not store those on variable.

Comment: i only know that if Status is none or blank then there should not be any alert

Comment: In that case you just have to change two lines of code in my answer.

Comment: Can you please update your answer? it will be more helpful

Comment: Upvote first, ask later. All statuses have to be none or blank to not fire the alert or just one is enough?

Comment: Not getting u. if possible please update your answer

Comment: I updated my answer but I was asking if every status column has to be none or blank to not fire the alert, because my code doesn't fire the alert only if all status are none or blank.

Comment: no. even if one cell of the status column is None then not fire the alert